# Linq Join tables, Group by date, Sum of values?

Tags: c#, linq, join, group-by, sum

I have two tables (one-to-many). `MeterReadings(0..1) and MeterReadingDetails(*)`

I want to join these tables and group by date. Date field is in MeterReadings and Others are in MeterReadingDetails.

I used this code:

**Linq**

```
public static IEnumerable<MeterReadingsForChart> GetCustomerTotal(int CustomerId, int MeterTypeId, DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate, MeterReadingsTimeIntervals DateRangeType)
{
    var customerReadings = from m in entity.MeterReadings
        join n in entity.MeterReadingDetails on m.sno equals n.ReadingId
        where m.Meters.CustomerId == CustomerId && m.ReadDate >= StartDate && m.ReadDate <= EndDate && m.Meters.TypeId == MeterTypeId
        group n by new { date = new DateTime(m.ReadDate.Value.Year, m.ReadDate.Value.Month, 1) } into g
        select new MeterReadingsForChart
        {
             ReadDate = g.Key.date,
             Value = g.Sum(x => x.Value),
             Name = g.FirstOrDefault().MeterReadingTypes.TypeName
         };

    return customerReadings;
}
```

**MeterReadinsForChart.cs**

```
public class MeterReadingsForChart
{
    public DateTime ReadDate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

But I got this error:

> Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities

How can I join, group, and sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var customerReadings = (from m in entity.MeterReadings
    join n in entity.MeterReadingDetails on m.sno equals n.ReadingId
    where m.Meters.CustomerId == CustomerId && m.ReadDate >= StartDate && m.ReadDate <= EndDate && m.Meters.TypeId == MeterTypeId
    group n by new { Year = m.ReadDate.Value.Year, Month = m.ReadDate.Value.Month} into g
    select new
    {
         Key = g.Key,
         Value = g.Sum(x => x.Value),
         Name = g.FirstOrDefault().MeterReadingTypes.TypeName
     }).AsEnumerable()
       .Select(anon => new MeterReadingsForChart
       {
         ReadDate = new DateTime(anon.Key.Year, anon.Key.Month, 1),
         Value = anon.Value,
         Name = anon.Name
       });
```

Unf. its ugly, but entity framework won't let you create a DateTime (being a struct it has no parameterless constructors). So in this case we want most of the result from the db and then as this streams we construct the date in memory.

Comment: This is the same with mine. And result is same, too.

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi sorry by that do you mean its giving the same error?

Comment: This code worked. Thanks I lot. But there is a way too. First step I get the records without gruping. And then convert it to list. Second step: group the list by date.

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi thanks for the feedback. The only thing to watch out for in your proposed scheme is that you are grouping in memory as opposed to on the server so for large data sets there could be a performance issue

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi as with most code related things use the most appropriate, I suggest testing both, if there's no real difference go with the most understandable